Feasible set formed by exclusion of two convex sets
I'm working on an optimal control problem which is almost entirely composed by elements of a quadratic programming problem. The decision variable is $u \in \mathbb{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is a convex set described by an LMI. The objective is given by $$ x_N^T Q x_N^{\phantom{T}} + \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i^T Q x_i^{\phantom{T}} u_i^T R u_i^{\phantom{T}}.$$
The challenge I'm facing is that I have an additional constraint that defines, through an LMI, a region in which the decision variable cannot take values. To better illustrate this situation I have included this example. The union of the green and blue regions correspond to the original constraint $u \in \mathbb{U}$, while the blue region corresponds to the exclusion region. My doubt is whether there is an efficient way to deal with this kind of problem, given the information I have (i.e., LMI descriptions of the the blue and blue+green regions).
My problem is similar to the one in this question, in which a Big M trick is mentioned. I'm not sure how or if this trick would be applicable to my problem, as I don't have descriptions of the disjoint feasible sets (green regions), but of the original constraint and the exclusion region (green+blue and blue).
